# AfterThrowing advice not working Spring AOP

Tags: spring, aop

I cannot get my afterThrowing Spring AOP advice to fire, 
I have made the point cut as generic as possible now and it still does not fire

I hope this is just a poor pointcut but I cannot see why, I would be grateful if anyone could see why

Advice

//Generic Exceptions

```
  @AfterThrowing(value = "execution(* *(..)) throws Exception", throwing = "exception")
    public void loggingGenericException(JoinPoint joinPoint, Exception exception) {
        String classMethod = this.getClassMethod(joinPoint);

        String stackTrace = "";
        for (StackTraceElement element : exception.getStackTrace()) {
            stackTrace += element.toString() + "\n";
        }

        String exceptionMessageAndStackTrace = exception.getMessage() + "\n" + stackTrace;

        if (exception instanceof EmptyResultSetException) {
            this.infoLevelLogging(joinPoint, classMethod);
        } else {

            this.errorLevelLogging(joinPoint, classMethod, exceptionMessageAndStackTrace);
        }
    }
```

Method that should be advised

```
public void getStudentTranscript(String studentId) throws RestClientException,IllegalArgumentException{


        if (!this.serviceUrl.isEmpty()) {

            if(studentId.isEmpty())
            {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("studentId empty");
            }

            this.transcript =  (Transcript) super.getForObject(this.serviceUrl,Transcript.class, studentId);




         } else {

             throw new IllegalArgumentException("url is empty");
         }

}
```

If I run a test to check it is applied it is not working the test looks like this

```
@Test
public void  testLoggingFiredOnExceptionInTranscriptRepository() throws Exception
{
    Log log;
    log = mock(Log.class);
    when(log.isErrorEnabled()).thenReturn(true);

    try {
        loggingAspects.setLogger(log);
        transcriptRepository.setServiceUrl("");
        transcriptRepository.getStudentTranscript("12345");
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        System.out.println("e = " + e);
        verify(log, times(1)).isErrorEnabled();
        verify(log, times(1)).error(anyString());

    }
}
```

The system out shows an exception fired

Can anyone offer any advice ( pun intended) :-)

Comment: Solved - problem with test setup

Comment: Can you share what was the solution, I am facing similar issue

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />` element in your spring configuration file? Otherwise, the AOP annotations won't be interpreted.

FYI, after having read your question, I created a sample project on my own and the `@AfterThrowing` annotation just works as it should.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the effort having looked back I had declared a new instance in my testcase setup - so it did not run in AOP context